# I'm working with the API, with ts+react, trying to display pictures, but react for some reason does not see the url field in the logo object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working with the API, with ts+react, trying to display pictures, but react for some reason does not see the url field in the logo object [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poi03.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY6NY.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZgdB.jpg)

I need to access the url field of the logo object, the map method also gives an error

Comment: Please add your code to the question rather than a screenshot of your code. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.